# Proving ${\frac{n+2}{2n+3}} $ converges to $\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I'd just like to verify whether I've done it correctly.

Proof strategy. First we determine what we need to set $N$ equal to;
$$\left|\frac{n+2}{2n+3}-\frac12\right|=\left|\frac{2n+4-(2n+3)}{4n+6}\right|= \frac1{4n+6}<\epsilon$$
Some rewriting get us,
$$n>\frac{1}{4\epsilon}-\frac{6}4{}$$
When $\epsilon$ is $\frac{1}{6}$ $N$ will be 0 but this is not allowed since N should be a positive integer. We notice:
$$n>\frac1{4\epsilon}>\frac1{4\epsilon} -\frac64$$
Hence choose $N=\lceil\frac1{4\epsilon}\rceil$

Proof: Let $\epsilon>0$ and choose $N=\lceil1/4\epsilon\rceil$. Let $n>N$ where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then $n>\frac1{4\epsilon}>\frac1{4\epsilon}-\frac64$ .

Thus, rewrite to get, $ \frac{1}{4n+6} < \epsilon$

Therefore, $$\left|\frac{n+2}{2n+3}-\frac12\right|=\left|\frac{2n+4-(2n+3)}{4n+6}\right|=\frac1{4n+6}<\epsilon$$

Hence the sequence converges to $\frac{1}{2}$. $$\space \blacksquare$$

Comment: $\frac{1}{4\epsilon}$ isn't always an integer, though. You can fix that by, for instance, using the ceiling function, or being less specific and saying that you pick an arbitrary $N$ greater than or equal to $\frac{1}{4\epsilon}$.

Comment: @Arthur I did so in my proof but forgot to include it in the proof strategy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is correct, apart from the part where you write "We notice n > ...". You should omit the part "n > " there and simply write "We notice $\frac1{4\varepsilon} > \frac1{4\varepsilon} - \frac64.$"